# How to set sysctl fs.notify.max_user_watches in GUIX? (guix system: error: service 'sysctl' provided more than once)

Tags: linux, gnu, inotify, sysctl

IDE's like PyCharm work better when `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` is set to a high level. How to do that in GUIX?

I recall that the approach by Draketo used to work up to a few months ago: https://www.draketo.de/software/guix-config.html

```
             (service sysctl-service-type
                      (sysctl-configuration
                       (settings '(("fs.file-max" . "500000")
                                   ("fs.inotify.max_user_watches" . "524288")))))
```

in `config.scm`.

E.g. this minimal `config.scm`

```
(use-modules (gnu))
(use-service-modules desktop xorg)

(operating-system
  (locale "en_US.utf8")
  (timezone "Europe/Amsterdam")
  (keyboard-layout
    (keyboard-layout "us" "us-intl"))
  (host-name "abcd")
  (services
    (append
      (list (service gnome-desktop-service-type)
             (service sysctl-service-type
                      (sysctl-configuration
                       (settings '(("fs.file-max" . "500000")
                                   ("fs.inotify.max_user_watches" . "524288")))))
      )
      %desktop-services))
  (bootloader
    (bootloader-configuration
      (bootloader grub-efi-bootloader)
      (target "/boot/efi")
      (keyboard-layout keyboard-layout)))
  (file-systems
    (cons* (file-system
             (mount-point "/")
             (device
               (uuid "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
                     'btrfs))
             (type "btrfs"))
           (file-system
             (mount-point "/boot/efi")
             (device (uuid "1111-1111" 'fat32))
             (type "vfat"))
           %base-file-systems)))
```

will give this error when using `guix system build -n config.scm`:

```
error: sysctl-service-type: unbound variable
hint: Did you forget `(use-modules (gnu services sysctl))'?
```

However, adding that line to the top:

```
(use-modules (gnu))
(use-service-modules desktop xorg)
(use-modules (gnu services sysctl))
(operating-system
...
```

or this

```
(use-modules (gnu))
(use-service-modules desktop xorg sysctl)
(operating-system
...
```

will lead to this error:

```
guix system: error: service 'sysctl' provided more than once
```

Guix is recent:

```
$ guix -V
guix (GNU Guix) 1b6e7157cd30ffc2b29779fe6d5cb4ddbbc6f331
```

Edit:

Possibly related bug report: " [PATCH] gnu: Harden filesystem links." https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=47013

Possibly related email thread: "How to compose sysctl-service-type?" https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-guix/2021-03/msg00066.html

Apparently outdated documentation: https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Miscellaneous-Services.html#Miscellaneous-Services which has this broken(?) example

```
(service sysctl-service-type
         (sysctl-configuration
           (settings '(("net.ipv4.ip_forward" . "1")))))
```

There is newer documentation https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guix.git/tree/doc/guix.texi with these instructions:

> Since `sysctl-service-type` is used in the default lists of
> services, `%base-services` and `%desktop-services`, you can
> use `modify-services` to change its configuration and add the
> kernel parameters that you want.

with this example

```
(modify-services %base-services
  (sysctl-service-type config =>
                       (sysctl-configuration
                         (settings (append '(("net.ipv4.ip_forward" . "1"))
                                           %default-sysctl-settings)))))
```

However it is unclear to me where to put that. Putting it after the `services` definition gives this error:

```
error: (modify-services %base-services (sysctl-service-type config => (sysctl-configuration (settings (append (quote (("net.ipv4.ip_forward" . "1"))) %default-sysctl-settings))))): invalid field specifier
```

Comment: Hmm, perhaps should have asked this on the Unix & Linux StackExchange; is it possible to move the question?

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example seems to work with `guix system build -n`:

```
(use-modules (gnu))
(use-service-modules desktop xorg sysctl)
(operating-system
  (locale "en_US.utf8")
  (timezone "Europe/Amsterdam")
  (keyboard-layout
    (keyboard-layout "us" "us-intl"))
  (host-name "abcd")
  (services
    (append
      (list (service gnome-desktop-service-type)
      )

      (modify-services %desktop-services
        (sysctl-service-type config =>
          (sysctl-configuration
            (settings (append '(("fs.file-max" . "500000")
                                ("fs.inotify.max_user_watches" . "524288"))
                               %default-sysctl-settings)))))

      ))

  (bootloader
    (bootloader-configuration
      (bootloader grub-efi-bootloader)
      (target "/boot/efi")
      (keyboard-layout keyboard-layout)))
  (file-systems
    (cons* (file-system
             (mount-point "/")
             (device
               (uuid "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
                     'btrfs))
             (type "btrfs"))
           (file-system
             (mount-point "/boot/efi")
             (device (uuid "1111-1111" 'fat32))
             (type "vfat"))
           %base-file-systems)))
```

The [new documentation](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guix.git/tree/doc/guix.texi) says to modify `%base-services`, but in this case it is necessary to modify `%desktop-services`, which seems to include `%base-services`. The `modify-services` command replaces the `%desktop-services` line.

Tested to work.